# Adding GTK child widget to main window on a function call

Tags: c++, c, widget, gtk

I am trying to add `GtkNotebook` widget in my `GtkWindow` widget. The window widget is created in the ui file along with the `GtkBox`.

```
myclass:: myclass()
{       
GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new();
gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "uifile.ui", NULL);
gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);
mainWindow = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "mainWindow"));
box = GTK_BOX (gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "box1"));
gtk_widget_show_all (mainWindow);
}
```

I have this function `void newTab` in myclass. And `view` is defined as `GtkWidget *view`.

```
void myclass:: newTab()
{
view = gtk_notebook_new();
gtk_notebook_set_tab_pos (GTK_NOTEBOOK (view), GTK_POS_TOP);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX (box),view, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
gtk_box_reorder_child (GTK_BOX (box), view, 1);
gtk_widget_show (view);
}
```

But I am getting a `segmentation fault` when I call this function.
Is this not the correct way to add the widget to my mainWindow?
How do I correct this?

For complete code of myclass.h and myclass.cpp file refer here http://pastebin.com/tWTUKtZG

Answer (score 0):

here I do it in python3, gtk3, which basically the same

```
class myclass ():
   def __init__ (self):   
      mainWindow = # construct from builder
      tab = self.newTab ()
      mainWindow.add (tab)

      mainWindow.show_all ()


   def newTab (self):
      view = Gtk.Notebook ()
      view.show ()
      return view

   # in C
   # GtkWidget* newTab ()
   # {
   #    view = Gtk.Notebook ()
   #    view.show ()
   #    return view
   # }
```

perhaps you added GtkWidget *view into mainWindow before you call void onTab () ?, if you did, do the opposite

Comment: Actually I have a menuitem that calls this `newTab()` function. And I am adding this `GtkWidget *view` in this function only.